# Regex in R lists to call specific function

Tags: r, regex, list

It is of course possible to store functions in a list to call it.
It is also possible to name that list entry to have a better access to it later.

Now I need the list item name to be a regular expression like this:

```
funcList <- list("^\\+[0-9]{1,3}$"=lead, "^\\-[0-9]{1,3}$"=lag)

a <- funcList$"+12"(a,12) # this will fire function "lead"
a <- funcList$"-4"(a,-4) # this will fire function "lag"


a <- funcList$"^\\+[0-9]{1,3}$"(a,12) # this works of course but is not what I want...
```

Of course this is not working correctly and I am getting the error "Error: attempt to apply non-function" because it is not used as regex but as a normal string value.

Is it possible to do what I need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the names of the array as parameters for grepl:

```
funcList <- list("^\\+[0-9]{1,3}$"=lead, "^\\-[0-9]{1,3}$"=lag)

f1 <- funcList[sapply(names(funcList), function(x) grepl(x,"+12"))][[1]]  
f2 <- funcList[sapply(names(funcList), function(x) grepl(x,"-4"))][[1]] 

> f1(seq(1,10))
 [1]  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 NA
> f2(seq(1,10))
 [1] NA  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
```

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can map strings like `"+4"` and `"-12"` to `lead`/`lag` more straightforwardly like:

```
set.seed(123)

df = data.frame(
    x = sample(1:20, 10)
)

shifted = function(x, shift) {
    direction = substr(shift, 1, 1)
    amount = as.integer(substr(shift, 2, nchar(shift)))
    if (direction == "+") {
        return(lead(x, amount))
    } else {
        return(lag(x, amount))
    }
}

df %>%
    mutate(
        plus4 = shifted(x, "+4"),
        minus3 = shifted(x, "-3")
    )
```

You could use regex within the `shifted` function if you need to do more validation of the `"+4"` strings, but I prefer not to go for complicated regexes unless they're definitely needed.

Comment: I need an easy way to add new functions to this list so your solution is not wrong but not optimal for me. This was just a simple example of two functions. The patterns of the following functions are not always decided on the first character.